# target="_blank" does not open new window

Tags: javascript, html

target="_blank" does not open new window and only navigates to the new page in the same window, as shown below:

```
<form onSubmit="return process();" target="_blank"> 
<input type="text" name="url" id="url"  placeholder="Product ID"> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form> 
<script>
function process(){
    var url= "https://myurl.com/products/" + document.getElementById("url").value.trim();
    location.href=url; return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your `process` function explicitly assigns to the current window's `location.href`...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the button, the code fires immediately, and so your code is navigating to another page but in the same tab.

`target="_blank"` works only if the form has an action to send the data to.

use `window.open(url)` instead.

```js
function process() {
  var url = "https://myurl.com/products/" + document.getElementById("url").value.trim();
  window.open(url);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="return process();" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Product ID"> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

---

Or in  your process function assign the url to the action attribute of the form, and remove`return false`

I named the form `f`

```js
function process() {
  var url = "https://myurl.com/products/" + document.getElementById("url").value.trim();
  document.f.setAttribute('action', url);

}
```

```html
<form onSubmit="return process();" name="f" target="_blank">
  <input type="text" name="url" id="url" placeholder="Product ID"> <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Happy To Help :)

Comment: @James If this is the correct answer, it should be marked as such.